# Completeness versus geodesic completeness

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cartan-geometry

**The question**: is it true that an affine connection which is geodesically complete is complete as a Cartan connection?

**Toy problem**: is it true for Lorentz metrics? (Surely this must be known.)

**Some of the definitions.**
Take an affine connection $\nabla$ on a manifold $M$.
Cartan's structure equations for any affine connection, in terms of the soldering forms $\omega^i$ and the connection forms $\omega^i_j$ on the frame bundle $FM$ of $M$ are
$$d\omega^i+\omega^i_j\wedge\omega^j=\frac{1}{2}t^i_{jk}\omega^j\wedge\omega^k$$
$$d\omega^i_j+\omega^i_k\wedge\omega^k_j=\frac{1}{2}k^i_{jk}\omega^j\wedge\omega^k$$
A *constant vector field* $X=X_{A,v}$ is a vector field on $FM$ so that
$$\omega^i(X)=v^i$$
$$\omega^i_j(X)=a^i_j$$
for a constant vector $v=(v^i)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and a constant matrix $A=(a^i_j)\in\mathfrak{gl}_n$.
Clearly $$X_{A,v}=X_{A,0}+X_{0,v}.$$
An affine connection is *complete as a Cartan connection* if these constant vector fields are complete.
On $FM\times\mathbb{R}^n$, the *geodesic vector field* is
$$
Z(p,v)=(X_{0,v}(p),0)
$$
for $p\in FM$, $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
This vector field descends under the diagonal $\operatorname{GL}_n$-action to a vector field (also called the *geodesic vector field*) on the quotient manifold $TM=FM\times^{\operatorname{GL}_n}\mathbb{R}^n$..
An affine connection is *geodesically complete* just when the geodesic vector field is a complete vector field.
Clearly an affine connection that is complete as a Cartan connection is geodesically complete. So the question could be rephrased as the equivalence, for affine connections, of geodesic completeness and completeness as a Cartan connection.
The problem has an obvious generalization to reductive Cartan geometries, but this is essentially the same problem, since these induce affine connections.

**History.**
Many authors have proofs that geodesic completeness implies completeness as a Cartan geometry (including me, to my embarrassment!), but the proofs are not very solid.
For example,

Kobayashi, Shôshichi
*[On connection of Cartan](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1956-018-8)*
**Canadian J. Math.**, 1956, Vol. 8
p. 145-156,
 [MR77978](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=77978), [Zbl 0075.31502](https://zbmath.org/0075.31502).

The method of proof is always the same.
Suppose that we have a geodesically complete affine connection.
The geodesic vector field is complete just when all $X_{0,v}$ are complete.
All $X_{A,0}$ are complete because they generate the action of the general linear group, the structure group, on the frame bundle.
So the *switchbacks* (or *Trotter products*)
$$
(e^{tX_{A,0}/n}e^{tX_{0,v}/n})^n
$$
are well defined.
One then hopes that their limit is defined.
If this hope is satisfied, we conclude by

Chorin, Alexandre J., McCracken, Marjorie F., Hughes, Thomas J. R., Marsden, Jerrold E. 
*[Product formulas and numerical algorithms](https://doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160310205)* 
**Comm. Pure Appl. Math.**, 1978, Vol. 31, No. 2
p. 205-256,
 [MR488713](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=488713), [Zbl 0358.65082](https://zbmath.org/0358.65082).

that the switchbacks converge to
$$
(e^{tX_{A,0}/n}e^{tX_{0,v}/n})^n\to e^{tX_{A,v}}
$$
and therefore $X_{A,v}$ is complete.
The problem step is always the convergence of the switchbacks.
Keep in mind that two complete vector fields need not have complete sum.

**The flat case.**
For flat Cartan geometries, geodesic completeness implies completeness by using a developing map to the homogeneous model of the Cartan geometry; for instance, flat affine connections which are geodesically complete develop to affine space by an isomorphism of each component of $M$.

**Invariant metrics.**
Another obvious trick: pick an inner product on $\mathfrak{gl}_n\oplus\mathbb{R}^n$, and use this to make a Riemannian metric on the frame bundle for which all $X_{A,v}$ have constant length. But the geodesic flow can be complete, and the Cartan connection can be complete, even when this metric is incomplete. See:

Clifton, Yeaton H. 
*[On the completeness of Cartan connections](https://doi.org/10.1512/iumj.1967.16.16038)*,
1967
**J. Math. Mech.**, Vol. 16, n° 6
p. 569-576,
 [MR205183](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=205183), [Zbl 0158.40402](https://zbmath.org/0158.40402).